# send data using bluetooth to android mobile without an app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, raspberry-pi3

I am working on iBeacon based project to send the push notification to Android devices using Bluetooth wireless technology. Is there any way to send the push notification to Android device without any installed app over the Bluetooth? Basically, iBeacon is connected to Pi using Bluetooth and Pi (Pi 3 with inbuilt Bluetooth) will communicate with Android devices using Bluetooth.  Following are the possible ways to send data/notification to Android devices:

- By an installed app
- Push notification through chrome using web-socket

But above both ways are not useful for my task. Kindly allow me to know if there is any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Nearby to send a notification to the device on beacon detection.  Tapping the notification can bring up a website or open a Google Play Store page to install your app.

https://developers.google.com/nearby/

Comment: Does it requires apps on Android device? I will go through the link suggested by you and let you know.

Comment: But Google Nearby requires the predefined app on the device. I want to send the push notification to all devices which are in proximity of iBeacons.

Comment: An app is not required.  Nearby can send a notification to the device when a beacon is encountered and when tapped the user can be taken to a web page.

Comment: I have gone through the link suggested by you i.e. https://developers.google.com/nearby/. It explains from App point of view. Can you please provide me an example? It is really helpful for me!  The content of NearBy (from official website): Nearby Messages exposes simple publish and subscribe methods that rely on proximity. Your app publishes a payload that can be received by nearby subscribers.

Comment: You register your beacons with Google as described here: https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/get-started then add an attachment with a URL as described here: https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/attachment_data_format

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to register iBeacon with Beacon Tools app both on Android and iOS. Both apps are not detecting iBeacon.